# How to retain values in a SAS dataset with datetime?

Tags: sas

I need help retaining values in a SAS dataset and completing the column datetime (to the level of seconds) when not existing.

My dataset looks like:

```
data HAVE;  
input type$ DATE:datetime18. value;
format date datetime18.;
cards;

A 19JUN01:21:06:55 534
A 19JUN01:21:06:58 590
A 19JUN01:21:07:02 600
A 19JUN01:21:07:04 602
B 18JUN01:22:06:58 105
B 18JUN01:22:07:03 110
;
run;
```

I need to fill the missing datetime and repeat the value when needed.

My result dataset should be:

```
data WANT;  
input type$ DATE:datetime18. value;
format date datetime18.;
    cards;

A 19JUN01:21:06:55 534
A 19JUN01:21:06:56 534
A 19JUN01:21:06:57 534
A 19JUN01:21:06:58 590
A 19JUN01:21:06:59 590
A 19JUN01:21:07:00 590
A 19JUN01:21:07:01 590
A 19JUN01:21:07:02 600
A 19JUN01:21:07:03 600
A 19JUN01:21:07:04 602
B 18JUN01:22:06:58 105
B 18JUN01:22:06:59 105
B 18JUN01:22:07:00 105
B 18JUN01:22:07:01 105
B 18JUN01:22:07:02 105
B 18JUN01:22:07:03 110
    ;
run;
```

Thanks for your suggestions.
Regards

Comment: Do you have a license for SAS/ETS? If so, proc timeseries is your best bet.

Comment: This is the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73282367/quickest-way-to-fill-in-missing-dates-in-a-sequence-sas/73282507#73282507  The posted solutions should work since date values (number of days) and datetime values (number of seconds) are both integers.

Comment: Thanks @Reeza but I don´t have SAS/ETS.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, it also help me your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SAS/ETS, `proc expand` will do the entire conversion for you with the `step` method.

```
proc expand data=have out=want to=second;
    by type;
    id date;

    convert value / method=step;
run;
```

If you don't, you can do this using a few DATA Steps.

First, create a template of all datetimes that you want for each by-group. We want something that looks like this:

```
type    date_start          date_end
A       19JUN01:21:06:55    19JUN01:21:07:04
B       18JUN01:22:06:58    18JUN01:22:07:03
```

The following code will do this:

```
data date_start_end;
    set have;
    by type date;
    retain date_start;

    if(first.type) then date_start = date;

    if(last.type) then do;
        date_end = date;
        output;
    end;

    format date_start date_end datetime.;

    keep type date_start date_end;
run;
```

Next, we need to create a template that fills in all the possible seconds between start/end for each type. We want something that looks like this:

```
type    date
A       19JUN01:21:06:55
A       19JUN01:21:06:56
A       19JUN01:21:06:57
         ...
B       18JUN01:22:07:01
B       18JUN01:22:07:02
B       18JUN01:22:07:03
```

The following code does this:

```
data date_template;
    set date_start_end;

    do date = date_start to date_end;
        output;
    end;

    format date datetime.;
    keep type date;
run;
```

Now we just need to merge this template with our original data and retain the last non-missing value.

```
data want;
    merge have(rename=(value = _value_) )
          date_template
    ;
    by type date;
    retain value;

    if(NOT missing(_value_) ) then value = _value_;

    drop _value_;
run;
```

Note that we rename `value` to `_value_` in the original dataset since retain will not work the way we expect after we merge. We need to create a new variable in order for it to retain properly.